# FreeImage - Write zTXt tag to PNG

Tags: .net, png, metadata, freeimage

This is really causing me a headache.  For some reason or another, I can add a specific tag to a PNG file, but it's not adding the way I'd like and I don't know how to get it to write the way I want

Given the code;

```
    Dim FImage As FIBITMAP = FreeImage.CreateFromBitmap(Image)

    Dim FTag As New Metadata.MetadataTag(FREE_IMAGE_MDMODEL.FIMD_COMMENTS)
    FTag.Key = "Description"
    FTag.ID = 270

    FTag.Value = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DescString.ToString)
    FTag.AddToImage(FImage)


    FreeImage.Save(FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT.FIF_PNG, FImage, fbSaveTo.SelectedPath & "\TEST.dmi", FREE_IMAGE_SAVE_FLAGS.EXR_ZIP Or FREE_IMAGE_SAVE_FLAGS.PNG_Z_BEST_COMPRESSION)
```

Assume that Image is valid and that DescString is too (it's a stringbuilder).  I'm trying to add the Image Description tag, which I want to have written *specifically* as a `zTXt` chunk in the PNG file, as I need to have that format in order for the file to be compatible with another target program (Dream Maker).  Instead, it writes an `iTXt` tag, which Dream Maker doesn't read which makes the file useless.

Can anyone familiar with FreeImage help me out, or could anyone recommend an alternative that I can integrate into my program?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out or do you know how to read .dmi files ztxt data in objective-c?